# How to wait for a function to return data from the observable response?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

From my home.ts, I'm calling a function in a service that populate an array with data from the firestore response (observable) but when I try to access this data from home.ts is undefined, because it's not waiting for the function to be finished. I've tried to wait with the await async but still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

home.ts

```
async addMarkers(){
    console.log("before await");
    let dataMarkers:MarkerOptions[] = await this.wcService.getWcData();
    console.log("after de await"); //executed before getWcData response
    console.log(dataMarkers); //Here is undefined
    ...`
```

wcService.ts

```
async getWcData() {
    let wcsCollection = this.db.collection<Wc>('wcs');
    wcsCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(res=>{
      res.forEach(element => {   
          this.addWcToMarkerOptionsArray(element.latitude,element.longitude,element);
          console.log("added element to this.markersWc");
      });
      console.log("returning results: " + this.markersWc);
      return this.markersWc;
    });
}
```

And the console log is showing in this order:
`"Before await"
"After await"
"returning results...."`

How can I force the function to wait for the result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Observable` to `Promise` by using `toPromise`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
```

then your service will be like that  :

```
async getWcData() {
    let wcsCollection = this.db.collection<Wc>('wcs');
    const result = await wcsCollection.valueChanges().toPromise();
    result.forEach(element => { 
      this.addWcToMarkerOptionsArray(element.latitude,element.longitude,element);
      console.log("added element to this.markersWc");
    });
    return this.markersWc;
}
```

Comment: Note that I'm returning an object created by myself in my wcService (MarkerOptions). 
If I use toPromise() I got the following error:

    ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(138,72): error TS2339: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Promise<MarkerOptions[]>'.

Comment: i Updated the answer , you can check it

Comment: Thanks for your help but still doesn't work, I'm sure i'm missing something. I've added toPromise as you said but now the code is hang on the valueChanges line and never goes further.

Answer (score 0):

The observable must complete before the promise resolves.
You solve the problem using the 'first' operator, which takes the first emitted value and then completes the composed observable:

```
async getWcData() {
    let wcsCollection = this.db.collection<Wc>('wcs');
    const result = await wcsCollection.valueChanges().first().toPromise();
    result.forEach(element => { 
      this.addWcToMarkerOptionsArray(element.latitude,element.longitude,element);
      console.log("added element to this.markersWc");
    });
    return this.markersWc;
}
```